# how to get log properties use regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have several log that info in the below, I would like to anylaze it that use regex expression in C#. I'd to get the datetime, thread,log type, model, log content.

Log:

2015-12-07 01:54:03,401 [7] INFO  MODEL1 - Log content(xxxxx)

Thanks and regards,
Einstein

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?  There are plenty of online regex testers with examples out there.

Comment: Are you sure to do it with regex? There is a lot of tools which can parse logs for you. If you looking for patterns you may look at [grok-patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex logline = new Regex(@"^(?<date>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).(?<thread>\d+) \[(?<logtype>\d+)\] Log content\((?<content>.*)\)$");

Match m = logline.Match(input);

if (m.Success)
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["date"].Value);
    int thread = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["thread"].Value);
    int logType = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["logType"].Value);
    var logContent = m.Groups["content"].Value;
}
```